# Error while trying to drop a row from pandas DataFrame index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I drop index 2019-08-01 from my dataFrame called Graph ?

```
             A            B          C       D           E           F
   Date                     
2019-08-01  0.000000    0.000000    0.000       NaN      NaN            NaN
2019-08-06  97.950000   98.050000   97.850  48.975000   48.975000   48.975000
2019-08-09  97.616667   97.508333   97.725  97.783333   97.783333   97.783333
2019-08-14  97.350000   97.325000   97.375  97.483333   97.483333   97.483333
2019-08-19  95.033333   94.791667   95.275  96.191667   96.191667   96.191667
```

I have used  the below code

```
Graph=Graph.drop(index='2019-08-01')
```

And got this error

```
KeyError: "['2019-08-01'] not found in axis"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try concart values to timestamp, because seems here is `DatetimeIndex`:

```
Graph=Graph.drop(index=pd.Timestamp('2019-08-01'))
```